# Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial ATI-Driver

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

I just updated my Ubuntu Trusty to Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial, everything works fine now, but I discovered a big problem with some packages:

**The author of the fglrx driver deleted the ppa for Xenial.**

I know there is a brand new driver, called *AMDGPU-PRO*, but my graphic card isn't supported by that driver.

Currently, I am using a *ATI Mobility Readeon 5450 Card* (Notebook).

It is possible to bring back the *fglrx-updates* to Xenial repesitory?

Answer (score 0):

Several websites mentioned that Catalyst/fglrx is not compatible with the newest X.org-version that Ubuntu 16.04 uses.
However the new driver AmdGPU-Pro does not support your graphics card either.

I have three solutions for you:

1. Install the OpenSource radeon-driver.
   It [supports your card](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver) and should work with all desktop environments with full 3D-Accelation except Unity.
   The only disadvantage is that your performance may suffer, because OpenSource-drivers tending to be unable to use the full performance of GPUs.
   If the driver isn't installed you just need to install the package xserver-xorg-video-ati .
2. If that not works and you're willing to test around try to downgrade X.org and install an old version from [this archive](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/f/fglrx-installer/) .
3. Downgrade your Ubuntu to 14.04 which is the last officially supported Ubuntu-version for your fglrx-driver.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for that answer, but I was looking for a version apart from the official releases or such like that. I am already utilize the offical radeon driver (My system came along with this default), but this driver is a kind of irritating, the performance isn't the best as you said. Furthermore I am not going to downgrade my System. Have you ever tried to downgrade a running system? This will end up in garbage I think so.

Comment: You're right with that. The only thing that keeps fglrx from working on your system is your X.org-version. As long as you don't downgrade that even a manual installation won't work or cause major bugs on your system.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a repository available that might help.

https://launchpad.net/~dokomix/+archive/ubuntu/fglrx-xenial

It seems to mostly work so far for me, there are some kinks to work out but that was always the case with fglrx.